# algorithm2e - Apply commands to content block of IF ... THEN ... ELSE

Tags: algorithm2e

In the following picture, I use a verbose but very pedagogical style for algorithms.

[image]

I would like to automatically use macros that act on the content of block like in the first example but with typing just the 2nd one. Juste see the MWE.  This will allow to always type the same LaTeX code but to use them in different.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[vlined]{algorithm2e}

    \newcommand\BlockIf[1]{\KwSty{Start If} \\ #1 \\ \KwSty{End If}}
    \newcommand\BlockElseIf[1]{\KwSty{Start Else If} \\ #1 \\ \KwSty{End Else If}}
    \newcommand\BlockElse[1]{\KwSty{Start Else} \\ #1 \\ \KwSty{End Else}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \uIf{1}{\BlockIf{if...}}
    \uElseIf{2}{\BlockElseIf{else if...}}
    \Else{\BlockElse{else...}}
\end{algorithm} 

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \uIf{1}{if...}
    \uElseIf{2}{else if...}
    \Else{else...}
\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant internal commands in `algorithm2e` are `\algocf@uIf`, `\algocf@uElseIf` and `\algocf@Else`.  The following modifications of these commands insert your extra formatting:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[vlined]{algorithm2e}

\newcommand\BlockIf[1]{\KwSty{Start If} \\ #1 \\ \KwSty{End If}}
\newcommand\BlockElseIf[1]{\KwSty{Start Else If} \\ #1 \\ \KwSty{End Else If}}
\newcommand\BlockElse[1]{\KwSty{Start Else} \\ #1 \\ \KwSty{End Else}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\algocf@uIf}[2]{\If@ifthen{#1}\If@noend{\BlockIf{#2}}}
\renewcommand{\algocf@uElseIf}[2]{\ElseIf@elseif{#1}\If@noend{\BlockElseIf{#2}}}
\renewcommand{\algocf@Else}[1]{\Else@else\If@endif{\BlockElse{#1}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \uIf{1}{if...}
    \uElseIf{2}{else if...}
    \Else{else...}
\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output]

The set-up for the display of if-then-else structures is dealt with by the command `\SetKwIF` which in standard form has 8 arguments, the first three of which are `If` `ElseIf` and `Else`.  It uses these names to build the commands modified above and a number of their variants e.g. for dealing with optional arguments `()` for adding comments.  You will need to redefine these variant commands too if you need that facility.

Comment: Thanks, I will look more precisely in the code of `algorithm2e` for more customization.